# CMake: how to properly distribuite CMake based libraries that will not be installed

Tags: cmake

It's said that library authors should ship their library with a config-file instead of a plain find-module.
Basically config-file are to be installed with the associated library on the system and can be used transparently by the user, whereas find-module is written by the user by his own when he finds out that the library hasn't any config-file.

But, what if I'm sure that my library will never be installed?
I'm doing embedded system development and it doesn't make much sense to install my static libraries on the system.
Different modules are organized as static libraries and handled by each project with git submodules.

Is there any way I can use config-files even in this scenario? Or, as library author, I should write a example of vanilla Find-module and say to client code "Take and copy this to your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`"?
Or maybe just tell the client code cmake to call `add_subdirectory`?

Comment: still worth to have it, supposing your static libs has compile definition -DUSE_FOO, c++ feature e.g. C++11. By providing a config file customer get everything for free even include paths etc. You should see config file as meta data associated to your static library that data only use for installation.
ps: do you use yocto for your embedded system ?

Comment: @MizuxDev Thank you for your comment. No, I'm not using yocto. Actually I do not use any system, i.e. it's bare metal. I organize code in static libraries just to separate different modules (e.g. RF driver library, sensor driver library, HALs, application code) and they are not supposed to be installed anywhere. They'll just lie in, let's say, a `third-party` directory and handled with git submodule.

Comment: @MizuxDev By any chance, is there any way to use config-files if I don't want them to be installed?

Comment: mm I think you must separate the `cmake; make install` needed in your "workspace" for dependencies generation to the final `make install` to ship your "product" which won't install deps since there are embedded as static in your app